# Is there a way to move a pointer from a queue to another?

Tags: c++11, queue, polymorphism

I need to take a pointer to an object stored in one queue, process it, and move to another queue that is in another object. Following, I'll show the structure (schematically) of the problem.

```
class A{
  public:
    A();
    ...
    // fields and methods
}

class B : public A{
  public:
    B();
    ...
    // extra fields and methods (not in A)
    
}
class C : public A{
  public:
    C();
    ...
    // extra fields and methods (not in A)
    
}


class Sender{
  public:
    Sender();
    std::queue<A*> qSender;
    ...
    // fields and methods
}

class Receiver{
  public:
    Receiver();
    std::queue<A*> qReceiver;
    void moveToReceiver(Sender& s, int n);
    ...
    // fields and methods
}
```

I've used the queue with pointer to base class to overcome the slicing object problem, but I don't know if is the best way to do. I've filled the `qSender` queue following the

`qSender.push_back(new B(...)));`

Then i've tried to move from a qSender to qReveiver with this code:

```
void moveToReceiver(Sender& s, int n){
  for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
    A* a = senderObject.qSender.front();
    senderObject.qSender.pop();
    qReceiver.push(a);
  }
}
```

But I've noticed that the elements are not being pop; the code is only "moving" `n` pointers to the first object to the `qReceiver` and not removing from  `qSender`.

Any ideas to solve that are welcome.

Comment: Yes, is std::queue. I'll make an edit now

Comment: Why do you think the ptr isn't removed from qSender?

Comment: because after that "moving" i print the content of both queue, and the result is what i've explained. the qSeneder have the same ptr and qReceiver have the same ptr  n times

Comment: Could you pls provide [example] so that I can see what you are doing?

Comment: a typo; is a (the pointer that is popped from the other queue)

Comment: @YaelTudela "_I've noticed that the elements are not being pop; the code is only "moving" `n` pointers to the first object to the `qReceiver` and not removing from `qSender`._" - I think it may be something in the code that you haven't shown. Did you try my example? Do you get the same problem with that?

Comment: @YaelTudela It's been a few weeks since you asked this question. Did you abandon it? Do you need help understanding my answer?

Comment: I've voted to close this question for lack of clarity. I thought I understood it when I answered - but I clearly did not.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simplified example. I've used `std::unique_ptr<A>` instead of a raw `A*` since that helps a lot to keep things safe.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>

class A {
public:
    A() = default;

    // A virtual base class destructor is a must if you are going to destroy objects
    // through a base class pointer:
    virtual ~A() = default;

    virtual void work() = 0;  // an example function
};

class B : public A {
public:
    void work() override { std::cout << "B working\n"; }
};

class C : public A {
public:
    void work() override { std::cout << "C working\n"; }
};

// Helper alias
using queue_type = std::queue<std::unique_ptr<A>>;

void moveToReceiver(queue_type& sender, int n, queue_type& receiver) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        // move the pointer out and put it in the new queue
        receiver.emplace(std::move(sender.front()));
        sender.pop();
    }
}

// Display and empty a queue:
void display(queue_type& q) {
    while(not q.empty()) {
        q.front()->work();
        q.pop();
    }
}

int main() {
    queue_type qSender;
    queue_type qReceiver;

    // Put two objects in qSender
    qSender.emplace(std::make_unique<B>()); // C++11: new B
    qSender.emplace(std::make_unique<C>()); // C++11: new C

    // Move the objects to qReceiver
    moveToReceiver(qSender, qSender.size(), qReceiver);

    std::cout << "qSender:\n";
    display(qSender);

    std::cout << "qReceiver:\n";
    display(qReceiver);
}
```

Both objects have been moved to `qReceiver`, so the output will be:

```
qSender:
qReceiver:
B working
C working
```